# Atomless measure algebra is direct sum of at most countably many homogeneous measure algebras

Tags: measure-theory

How can we prove the following theorem from *Measure Theory Vol II* (page 280) by Vladimir?

> **9.3.5. Theorem.** (i) Every atomless measure algebra is the direct sum of at most countably many homogeneous measure algebras.
>
> (ii) Every atomless homogeneous measure algebra corresponding to a
>   probability measure is isomorphic to the measure algebra generated by
>   certain power of unit intervals with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Seirios The Question states as "Need the proof"

Answer (score 1):

That is the classification theorem of Maharam. The result is highly nontrivial, but the original paper with proof is available [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078424/). Of ourse, the reference is given in Bogachev's book.

The most readable proof I know is the one given by Fremlin in the article "Measure Algebras" in the *handbbok of Bolean Algebras Vol 3*, edited by Monk.

Comment: I am aware of that paper but as you know that one is very strong and not easy to understand for baby mathematicians. I need an explicit proof if possible. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AlexandroMrose I added a reference to a more accessible exposition. But the proof *is* hard.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.